# set click in a view in recycleview and change another icon a views recycleview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want when the user, for example clicked on a play button in the first view inside recycler view, another view say second view in recycler view change to play button image. But android studio get a error and say

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference

**if user click in button1 then button 2 change image button only  in list of recycle view** 
***OR user click in everyone button change button[2].image***

My code is here down please help me

```
public class DataAdapter33 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter33.MyViewHolder> {
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
public int i=0;
Context context;
Handler Myhandler;
public byte[] Image = null;
private List<Data> DataList = new ArrayList<>();
public DataAdapter33(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
public void setData(List<Data> DataList) {
    this.DataList = DataList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnTouchListener {
    public TextView id, setter, singer, musicName, arrengment;
    public ImageButton btn_ring, btn_loop, btn_download;
  public   ImageButton btnplay_stop[] = new ImageButton[9];
    public String url = null;
    public SeekBar seekBarProgress;
    public int mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds; // gets the song length in milliseconds from URL
    public final Handler handler = new Handler();
    public ImageView image;
    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        i++;
        musicName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TitleMusic);
        arrengment = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.arangement);
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.artistimage);
      btnplay_stop[i] = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay_Puase);
        btn_download = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);
        btn_loop = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLoop);
        btn_ring = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnring);
        seekBarProgress = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.SeekBarTestPlay);
        seekBarProgress.setMax(99); // It means 100% .0-99
        seekBarProgress.setOnTouchListener(this);
           btnplay_stop[i].setTag(i);
        btnplay_stop[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_download.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_loop.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_ring.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnPlay_Puase: {
                int index = (Integer) v.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(context, ""+index, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnplay_stop[2].setImageResource(R.drawable.disconenct);
            }
            break;
            case R.id.btnDownload:
                break;
            case R.id.btnLoop:
                break;
            case R.id.btnring:
                break;
        }
    }
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycle_musics_view, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    Log.d("DataAdapter", "On Create View Holder Called ");
    return holder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Data data = DataList.get(position);
    Log.d("DataAdapter", "On BindView Holder " + position);
    holder.musicName.setText(data.getMusicName());
    holder.arrengment.setText(data.getArrengment());
    holder.url = data.getUrl();
    MyrunUI m=new MyrunUI();
    m.runin(context,holder,data);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return DataList.size();
}
}
```

I do not no english please help 
**If user click in button1 then button 2 change image button only  in list of recycle view** 
or
***OR user click in everyone button change button[2].image***
thanks

image of my abstract code
My Error in android studio
[image]

Comment: The `btnplay_stop[2]` is not initialising anywhere. Or the way you initialising it might not be correct.

Comment: You want the same image button has to be replaced with different image right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into your code, can you please tell me size of your data? Everytime you call viewHolder, you increment value of i and as per that value you initialize your image buttons. But in onclick you specify only second index of image buttons array. It may happen that your data size would be less than 2 or for any other reason it can not be initialized and that is why it is giving you NullPointer there.

Comment: Tankyou for help my brother